# MongoDB aggregate specify criteria?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb `aggregate` to get already filtered data in response on my node server.

```
Some.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: '$model',
        someAvg: { $avg: '$some' },
        someAvg2: { $avg: '$some2' },
        someSum3: { $sum: '$some3' }
    }}
], function (err, results) {
    ...
```

But all this does is returns the Models without duplicates and averages `some, some2, some3` of these models. When you are using find, you can specify something like:

```
Some.find({model:"Thinkpad T430"}, function(...
```

So it returns only data sells with `model` value of `"Thinkpad T430"`.

**Is there a way to do the similar thing with `aggregate`?**

Comment: I think you need $match http://goo.gl/1S6Ioj. Could you specify what do  you want to get as result ? Also, what data do you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Some.aggregate([
    { $match : { 
        model:"Thinkpad T430"
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: '$model',
        someAvg: { $avg: '$some' },
        someAvg2: { $avg: '$some2' },
        someSum3: { $sum: '$some3' }
    }}
], function (err, results) {
    ...
```